# Does any scripture state Ravana to be a great Astrologer?

Tags: scripture, astrology, ravana

Many people say that Ravana was having immense knowledge of astrology.
Which texts support this statement?

Comment: Maybe due to [Ravana Samhita](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/ravan-samhita-biggest-edition-ever-nze100/)

Comment: @Vivikta In the first page of the book , there is a sentence on top (मेघनाद विरचितं) . Does that mean it was originally composed by Meghanad??Do we have any cross reference for this??

Comment: I'm not much aware of this actually, This will need some research! ;)  @ShriRambhakt